# Can't read MySql String VALUES

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

[image]
Same code I used on Access.
Now I am using MySql on a server PC.
`INSERT INTO` doesn't work, but when `SELECT` statement only, check the commented code, it works, it displays what I am looking for, so what's wrong?

Comment: It is very inconvenient to read from image, add code and error message.

Comment: If you _ever_ plan to publish you application, start using parameterized sql queries ASAP. Why? It's **easier** ¹ AND **safer** ².  1: [MySqlParameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html), 2: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string values need quote marks like

```
VALUES ('Paderes','Jean', etc
```

Comment: That mistake though, nearly forgot about it, I was using parameters on the other one, I just tried this line for testing. anyway thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
VALUES ('Paderes', 'Jean', 'Fernandez', 'RND', 'Jean','1234')
```